# URL Masking in address bar

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-masking, domain-masking

I have an application in my server for example at www.myDomain.com/pos, my client wants to run this application with his domain name As: www.clienDomain.com/pos. 
But i don't want to install my application to client server. is there any way to access my server with clientDomain name?

Comment: I think you could have the client's server make a proxy request to your server.

Comment: ...or just have him point the DNS to your server.

Comment: what is the process ? could you explain please??

Comment: See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/proxy.html.

Answer (score 1):

Yes very possible.

If your client is running Apache, and has `mod_proxy` installed, most do by default.

Then you can use `.htaccess` directives like so:

```
ProxyPassReverse "/pos" "http://example.com/pos"
```

> In addition, reverse proxies can be used simply to bring several servers into the same URL space.

More info here:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass